# $(r_1 − r) (r_2 − r)(r_3 − r) = 4 Rr^ 2 $

Tags: triangles

We have to prove 
$(r_1− r) (r_2− r)(r_3− r) = 4 Rr^2$

I know the following formula , But I could not understand how to use them

[image]

Comment: Use $r=\frac{\Delta}{S}$

Comment: Heron's formula (which I don't see here) would be helpful: $\Delta^2 = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$. Otherwise, if you're supposed to just use a bunch of formulas, then plugging in the formulas in VIII(a) and IX(a) would give a series of straightforward computations (e.g. $r_1-r = \frac{\Delta a}{s(s-a)}$, and similarly for the others).

Answer (score 3):

We have 
\begin{align}
(r_1-r)(r_2-r)(r_3-r)&= \left(\frac{\Delta}{s-a} - \frac{\Delta}{s}\right)\left(\frac{\Delta}{s-b} - \frac{\Delta}{s}\right)\left(\frac{\Delta}{s-c}-\frac{\Delta}{s}\right)\\
&={\Delta}^3 \left(\frac{ abc}{s^3(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\right)\\
&=\frac{abc{\Delta}^2}{s^2\Delta}\\
&=4R{\left(\frac{\Delta}{s}\right)}^2\\
&=4Rr^2.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We know $$r = 4R\sin \frac{A}{2}\sin \frac{B}{2}\sin \frac{C}{2}$$ Thus, $$r_1-r = 4R\sin \frac{A}{2}\cos \frac{B}{2}\cos \frac{C}{2} -4R\sin \frac{A}{2}\sin \frac{B}{2}\sin \frac{C}{2} = 4R\sin ^2 \frac{A}{2}$$ Similarly it can be shown that: $$r_2-r = 4R\sin ^2 \frac{B}{2} \text{  and that   } r_3-r = 4R\sin ^2\frac{C}{2}$$ Thus, $$(r_1-r)(r_2-r)(r_3-r) = 64R^3\sin^2\frac{A}{2}\sin ^2\frac{B}{2}\sin ^2\frac{C}{2} = 4R(4R\sin \frac{A}{2}\sin \frac{B}{2}\sin \frac{C}{2})^2 = 4Rr^2$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: VIII(b) and IX(b) also can be used to the same effect